# change / set gcloud os login username?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

So simple enough question.

I am adding a new account to my compute engine.
I have added the user and the roles and all that fun stuff.
Now I am wanting to add the ssh key, which I am doing by running `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file .....`

this works fine, it creates the correct information and everything like that and I can login correctly with ssh, however, the username is really long and annoying.  I understand that it is generated by the email address, but this is just plain ugly and will get really annoying to type out each time I need to do something username based.

Is there anyway to change this, so instead of it being `ext_matthias_email_com` it's just `matthias` without having to add the 'ssh key' as meta data to the server?

thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using OS Login, **you can use** `username` instead of `username_domain.com` **for your G Suite organization**, and **you can't change it if you're an individual customer**.

Usually, if you follow documentation [Setting up OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access), after enabling OS Login you'll get something like this:

```
    $ gcloud compute ssh os-login-instance-1
    ...
    username_domain_com@os-login-instance-1:~$ whoami
    username_domain_com
```

As it was expected, **full e-mail address was transformed and all dots and special characters was replaced by an underscore** accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages), and the main reason for it is **uniqueness**:

> If a username is not set by a G Suite administrator, OS Login
>   generates a default Linux username by combining the username and
>   domain from the email associated with the user's Google profile. **This
>   naming convention ensures uniqueness**. For example, if the user email
>   associated with the Google profile is `user@example.com`, then their
>   generated username is `user_example_com`.

```
username@domain.com becomes -> username_domain_com
```

**To change username_domain_com to username** accordingly to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages) you should have G Suite organization:

> **G Suite organizations can optionally change their default to remove
>   the domain suffix for newly generated usernames.** For example, if the
>   user email associated with the Google profile is `user@example.com`,
>   then their generated username is `user`. For more information, see
>   [Managing the OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#manage-oslogin-api).

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/692) you can find more details why it works in that way:

> OS Login ties your Linux user account to your Google identity so that
>   you have a consistent username, UID, and other posix information, in
>   every VM you log into. This allows the VM to authorize your login
>   using IAM permissions so that you can easily revoke access. **The
>   posix information is immutable for consumer identities (non-G Suite
>   users)**. This prevents a bad actor from setting information in a
>   malicious way that a project owner cannot manage. In order to prevent
>   uniqueness conflicts across different organizations (`user@gmail.com`
>   and `user@example.com`) the domain name is included by default.

Comment: Thanks Sherii, I will give that a shot and see if that helps.
its not really an issue. more of an annoyance, and what you have said above does make sense

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know if it was helpful or if you need more details.