# GCE: OS login without domain suffix name

Tags: google-compute-engine

### probrem

I am Google workspace user and using Google Compute Engine. I enabled OS login for our project, then login username changed to `username_with_domain_suffix`.
Now I would like to change my username as `username` with enabled-OS login, so I checked following document and ask workspace admin to turn checkbox [*OS Login API and Include domain suffix in user names generated by the OS Login API* ] off in Google Admin Console.
Although our admin change settings, my login user does not change and still being `username_with_domain_suffix`. Are there any other settings required to login with user without domain suffix? Thanks.

### reference

[change / set gcloud os login username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629476/change-set-gcloud-os-login-username)

Answer (score 0):

Even the check box turned off at Google admin, previously created username won't change. Only the new os-login user will be affected. I think this is because the (posix) username is created at first use of os-login and do not change after that.
In this case, you can use Google Directory API to update your existing posix account information stored at Google Directory.
I had exact same issue and was able to update my posix username with that.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#modify-users

API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update

You'd need to be a Google Workspace Admin(not GCP) to update it. I used "Try this method" in the API link. No need to write a code. But be careful, you may ruin your account info there.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try update via API link following your comment.